# How can we use filter in ng-repeat when iterating on an object in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Search field binded to a model

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchVoucher" />
```

An object iterated in ng-repeat

```
<li ng-repeat="(k,f) in {'r':4,'e':5,'t':6,'y':7,'c':8} | filter:searchVoucher">{{f}}</li>
```

How can i filter based on the object's key or val or val can also be an object having attributes.

Please help

Comment: what is the desired output

Comment: to be able to filter out elements based on the searchVoucher value. Say searchVoucher=4, then only one <li> is to be displayed in DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<li ng-repeat="(k,f) in {'r':4,'e':5,'t':6,'y':7,'c':8} | searchfilter:searchVoucher">{{f}}</li>
```

Filter

```
app.filter('searchfilter', function() {
  return function(input, term) {
    var regex = new RegExp(term || '', 'i');
    var obj = {};
    angular.forEach(input, function(v, i){
      if(regex.test(v + '')){
        obj[i]=v;
      }
    });
    return obj;
  };
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lRkvtMyIuscsvIIZn8CA?p=preview)

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks. Appreciate your prompt reply and elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/fFLUH/.
Here the same filter `searchVoucher` is configured to filter the input based on key or value, based on the `filterParam`.
The keyword `this` that is passed from `li` reffers to the controller `tst`.
This `tst` controller has the model for the textboxes.

Inside the filter, im accessing the `filterParam`, and using that to filter the input json.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Learned something new from your fiddle ;). However the solution given by Arun is what i needed. Thanks again. Appreciate your help.